# OllyDBG translate ASM to C

Tags: disassembly, ollydbg

I'm trying to reverse engineer an library function back to C/C++ code. 
But the function that I reverse is almust done, i just need a little bit help for making it compleet.

Here is the assembly code:

```
        0002BB46 | 8B 45 F4                 | mov eax,dword ptr ss:[ebp-C]                                            |
    0002BB49 | 8B 88 EC 00 00 00        | mov ecx,dword ptr ds:[eax+EC]                                           |
    0002BB4F | 89 4D EC                 | mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-14],ecx                                           |
    0002BB52 | 8B 55 F4                 | mov edx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-C]                                            |
    0002BB55 | 8B 82 F0 00 00 00        | mov eax,dword ptr ds:[edx+F0]                                           |
    0002BB5B | 89 45 F0                 | mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-10],eax                                           |
    0002BB5E | 83 7D EC 00              | cmp dword ptr ss:[ebp-14],0                                             |
    0002BB62 | 0F 8E BA 00 00 00        | jle TestDLL.2BC22                                                   |
    0002BB68 | C7 45 E8 00 00 00 00     | mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-18],0                                             |
    0002BB6F | EB 09                    | jmp TestDLL.2BB7A                                                   |
    0002BB71 | 8B 4D E8                 | mov ecx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-18]                                           |
    0002BB74 | 83 C1 01                 | add ecx,1                                                               |
    0002BB77 | 89 4D E8                 | mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-18],ecx                                           |
    0002BB7A | 8B 55 E8                 | mov edx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-18]                                           |
    0002BB7D | 3B 55 EC                 | cmp edx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-14]                                           |
    0002BB80 | 0F 8D 9C 00 00 00        | jge TestDLL.2BC22                                                   |
    0002BB86 | 8B 45 FC                 | mov eax,dword ptr ss:[ebp-4]                                            |
    0002BB89 | 50                       | push eax                                                                |
    0002BB8A | 6A 01                    | push 1                                                                  |
    0002BB8C | 6A 04                    | push 4                                                                  |
    0002BB8E | 8B 4D E8                 | mov ecx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-18]                                           |
    0002BB91 | 6B C9 14                 | imul ecx,ecx,14                                                         |
    0002BB94 | 03 4D F0                 | add ecx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-10]                                           |
    0002BB97 | 51                       | push ecx                                                                |
    0002BB98 | FF 15 38 E1 02 00        | call dword ptr ds:[<&fwrite>]                                           |
0002BB9E | 83 C4 10                 | add esp,10                                                              |
0002BBA1 | 8B 55 FC                 | mov edx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-4]                                            |
0002BBA4 | 52                       | push edx                                                                |
0002BBA5 | 6A 01                    | push 1                                                                  |
0002BBA7 | 6A 04                    | push 4                                                                  |
0002BBA9 | 8B 45 E8                 | mov eax,dword ptr ss:[ebp-18]                                           |
0002BBAC | 6B C0 14                 | imul eax,eax,14                                                         |
0002BBAF | 8B 4D F0                 | mov ecx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-10]                                           |
0002BBB2 | 8D 54 01 04              | lea edx,dword ptr ds:[ecx+eax+4]                                        |
0002BBB6 | 52                       | push edx                                                                |
0002BBB7 | FF 15 38 E1 02 00        | call dword ptr ds:[<&fwrite>]                                           |
```

an little explination: 
- You see on line 0002BB46 the assembly code:  mov eax,dword ptr ss:[ebp-C]
The [ebp - C] means that this is an structure.

and the part of 0002BB86, you see:  mov eax,dword ptr ss:[ebp-4] 
The [ebp - 4] means that this is an FILE*

But this is all that i know, I just need a little example for what this part do.
ASM 1:

```
 0002BB46 | 8B 45 F4                 | mov eax,dword ptr ss:[ebp-C]                                            |
0002BB49 | 8B 88 EC 00 00 00        | mov ecx,dword ptr ds:[eax+EC]                                           |
0002BB4F | 89 4D EC                 | mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-14],ecx                                           |
0002BB52 | 8B 55 F4                 | mov edx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-C]                                            |
0002BB55 | 8B 82 F0 00 00 00        | mov eax,dword ptr ds:[edx+F0]                                           |
0002BB5B | 89 45 F0                 | mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-10],eax
```

And the second one:

```
0002BB8E | 8B 4D E8                 | mov ecx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-18]                                           |
0002BB91 | 6B C9 14                 | imul ecx,ecx,14                                                         |
0002BB94 | 03 4D F0                 | add ecx,dword ptr ss:[ebp-10]                                           |
0002BB97 | 51                       | push ecx
```

i know it takes the variabele ebp18 and multiply it with 0x14. 
And add it to ebp10. But i dont know what ebp10 is. i whas thinking it is an struct or something.

I hope someone can help me, for explaining to me.

Manny thanks.

Here is the source code that I've from the assembly.

```
typedef struct _EDX  
{

    DWORD offset0;         // edx 0x0 -> needs tp be checked          
    DWORD offset4;        // edx 0x4                                  
    char offset64[0x64];  // edx 0x64                                 
    char offsetC8[0x20];  // -> new added                             
    DWORD offsetE8;       //                                          
    DWORD offsetEC;       // edx 0xEC                                 
    char* offsetF0;       // edx 0xF0                                

    char first[0x64];
} EDX, *PEDX;

bool _cdecl WriteAdptInfo(char* filName, PEDX ebpc) 
{
    if(ebpc != NULL)
    {
        FILE* file = fopen(filName, "wb");
        if(file != NULL)
        {
            size_t size1 = fwrite(&ebpc->offset4 , sizeof(DWORD), 0x01 ,file); 
            DWORD var8 = 0; 
            for(var8; var8 <= ebpc->offset4; var8++) 
            {
                DWORD a = var8 * 0xF4;
                PEDX ebpC = ebpc;
                ebpC->offset0 += a;
                size_t size2 = fwrite(ebpC->first, sizeof(char), sizeof(ebpC->first), file);
                size_t size3 = fwrite(ebpC->offset64, sizeof(char), sizeof(ebpC->offset64), file);
                size_t size4 = fwrite(ebpC->offsetC8, sizeof(char), sizeof(ebpC->offsetC8), file);
                size_t size5 = fwrite(&ebpC->offsetE8, sizeof(DWORD), 0x1, file);
                size_t size6 = fwrite(&ebpC->offsetEC, sizeof(DWORD), 0x1, file);

                DWORD var14 = ebpC->offsetEC;
                char* var10 = ebpC->offsetF0;

                if(var14 >= 0)
                {
                    DWORD var18 = 0;
                    for(var18; var18 <= var14; var18++)
                    {
                        DWORD counter = (var18 * 0x14);
                        //     ptr , size, count, file
                        size_t size7 = fwrite((counter + var10), sizeof(char*), 0x1, file);
                        size_t size8 = fwrite(var10 +counter + 0x4, sizeof(char*), 0x1, file);
                        size_t size9 = fwrite(var10 + counter + 0x8, sizeof(char*), 0x1, file);
                        size_t sizeA = fwrite(var10 + counter + 0xC, sizeof(char*), 0x1, file);
                        size_t sizeB = fwrite(var10 + counter + 0x10, sizeof(char*), 0x1, file);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        fclose(file);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 0002BB55 | 8B 82 F0 00 00 00        | mov eax,dword ptr ds:[edx+F0]                                           |
    0002BB5B | 89 45 F0                 | mov dword ptr ss:[ebp-10],eax   your ebp-10 is filled up here it was whatever was there in the [edx+f0]  first define the structure  and its members and then re read the assembly to correlate

Comment: So if i understand, it well, the F0 is the offset of the structure? Its simular to this assembly:   MOV EDX, DWORD PTR SS:[EBP - 10]    ADD EDX, F0

Comment: What do you have, in C *or* C++? (These are 2 different languages.)

Comment: @Avo18 no that is not correct i added an answer take a look )

Comment: @Rad Lexus below you can find my C++ code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the assembly in question has some structure defined and manipulates some members of the structure

the code in c/c++ could look something similar to whats shown in source window and the disassembly that you are working with is highlighted in blue 
in the screen shot below

[image]

Comment: which tool is this

Comment: Windbg ,,,,,,,,,,